# Combinatorics squares

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> Calculate the number of smaller rectangles (including squares) that are contained in a n × n grid (such as the smaller grey rectangle in the 5 × 5 grid below), by first considering choosing the sides of the rectangles.

How do I answer this given the following method that is stated also the image is attached

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngn07.jpg
This is my attempt to answer:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/epJuK.jpg

Comment: Are you only counting rectangles with horizontal or vertical orientation? (As opposed to "tilted" rectangles?)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Simultaneously choose two distinct vertical lines and simultaneously choose two distinct horizontal lines.

Given such a selection of lines, we can uniquely describe one of the rectangles.

Are all such rectangles described in such a way?  Are we sure that each rectangle is described uniquely in such a way?  Finally, how many ways are there to have chosen these pairs of lines?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see an image but I assume you are meant to first choose $2$ vertical edges from the $n+1$ available. This can be done in  $\begin{pmatrix}n+1\\2\\\end{pmatrix}$ ways.

Doing the same for horizontal edges gives the same number of choices and so there are $$\begin{pmatrix}n+1\\2\\\end{pmatrix}^2$$ rectangles.

Comment: Hi thank you I think I’ve done this but idk if it’s write so I added my answer to the solution. Does this look ok

Comment: Yes, that's great